# Modify MPAndroidChart without custom views

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

i'm using this library : https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart for creating charts in my app. At this moment i'm trying to match `BarChart` with needed design, here's what i've got : [image]

Here's my code from creating `BarChart` :

```
mBarChart = (BarChart)view.findViewById(R.id.chart);
mBarChart.setData(getData());
mBarChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
mBarChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
mBarChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
```

I have two questions :

***1. Why charts are stick to left for first and right for second, is there are any way to make them both centered?***

***2. As you can see, above this charts are labels : "All Barnstable HS Teams" and "Another title". Is there a way to control position and style of this textViews?***

**Any help highly appreciated**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered on second part of my question :

```
XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();//This is upper titles
```

From now on you can customize this value :

```
xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
xAxis.setSpaceBetweenLabels(0);
xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
xAxis.setTextSize(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.bar_chart_title_text_size));
```

And this will result in titles pushed below the chart and `textSize` customization, as well there is an option for setting `Typeface` and so on

Still trying to understand why charts aren't centered though